# Ramanujan's transformation formula connected with $r_{2}(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request

Let $r_{2}(n)$ denote the number of ways in which a positive integer $n$ can be expressed as the sum of squares of two integers. Here the sign as well as order of summands matters. Also by convention we set $r_{2}(0) = 1$. Bruce C. Berndt and George E. Andrews mention the following surprising result of Ramanujan related to $r_{2}(n)$ in their book "Ramanujan's Lost Notebook Vol 4" (page 10): $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{r_{2}(n)}{\sqrt{n + a}}e^{-2\pi\sqrt{(n + a)b}} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{r_{2}(n)}{\sqrt{n + b}}e^{-2\pi\sqrt{(n + b)a}}\tag{1}$$ where $a, b$ are positive real numbers.

It is further mentioned that this formula was referred in a paper ("On the expression of a number as the sum of two squares", Quart. J. Math. (Oxford)46(1915), 263–283.) by G. H. Hardy and was not seen anywhere in any of Ramanujan's published/unpublished work.

Like Ramanujan Berndt / Andrews also don't provide the proof in their book. The only detail I know about $r_{2}(n)$ is its generating function $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}r_{2}(n)q^{n} = \vartheta_{3}^{2}(q) = \left(\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}q^{n^{2}}\right)^{2} = 1 + 4\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{q^{n}}{1 + q^{2n}}\tag{2}$$ (see [this post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-fourier-series.html)) from which it is possible to find a direct formula for $r_{2}(n)$ based on count of divisors of $n$ of type $(4m + 1)$ and of type $(4m + 3)$. On the other hand the formula $(1)$ seems to based on some formula related to the sum $$\sum r_{2}(n)e^{-2\pi\sqrt{(n + a)b}}$$ and then taking its derivative with respect to $a$ to get $$-b\pi\sum \frac{r_{2}(n)}{\sqrt{(n + a)b}}e^{-2\pi\sqrt{(n + a)b}}$$ But when I try to integrate RHS of $(1)$ with respect to $a$ it leads to nowhere. My guess is that it is difficult to obtain $(1)$ as a derivative of some simpler identity.

Any proof of the formula $(1)$ or any reference containing a proof of $(1)$ is desired.

Comment: Let's create `ramanujan.stackexchange.com` ! :-$)$

Comment: @lucian: i wonder if there are so many users interested in Ramanujan. perhaps we should try creating a tag here itself.

Comment: I thought about that myself, but then I figured that I could just use the search option. *Then again*, we might just give it a shot... Just make sure to ask it on *meta* first, to get the community's reaction.

Comment: @Lucian I do not know if this was a joke, but I like the idea! :-)

Comment: @Lucian: I have put the question on meta http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20997/should-a-tag-for-ramanujan-mathematics-be-created

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We have the identity $$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{r_{2}\left(n\right)}{\sqrt{n+a}}e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\left(n+a\right)b}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n\geq0}r_{2}\left(n\right)\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(n+a\right)x-\pi^{2}b/x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}. \tag{1}$$ In fact $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(n+a\right)x-\pi^{2}b/x}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\left(n+a\right)b}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(\sqrt{\left(n+a\right)x}-\pi\sqrt{b/x}\right)^{2}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}
 $$ $$\overset{x=\frac{u}{n+a}}{=}\frac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\left(n+a\right)b}}}{\sqrt{n+a}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(\sqrt{u}-\pi\sqrt{b\left(n+a\right)/u}\right)^{2}}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}\overset{v=\sqrt{u}}{=}\frac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\left(n+a\right)b}}}{\sqrt{n+a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\left(v-\pi\sqrt{b\left(n+a\right)}/v\right)^{2}}dv $$ and we recall that if $f $ is an integrable function and $k>0 $, holds (see [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/963490/72031)) $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x-\frac{k}{x}\right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)dx
 $$ hence $$=\frac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\left(n+a\right)b}}}{\sqrt{n+a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-v^{2}}dv=\frac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\left(n+a\right)b}}}{\sqrt{n+a}}\cdot\sqrt{\pi} $$ so we can write $(1)$ as $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax-\pi^{2}b/x}\left(\sum_{n\geq0}r_{2}\left(n\right)e^{-nx}\right)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax-\pi^{2}b/x}\theta^{2}\left(x\right)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}
 $$ where $\theta\left(x\right)=1+2e^{-x}+2e^{-4\pi x}+\dots
 $ and, recalling the functional identity $$\theta\left(x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}}\theta\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{x}\right)
 $$ we have $$=\sqrt{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax-\pi^{2}b/x}\theta^{2}\left(\frac{\pi^{2}}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n\geq0}r_{2}\left(n\right)\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax-\pi^{2}\left(b+n\right)/x}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}}=
 $$ $$=\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n\geq0}r_{2}\left(n\right)e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\left(n+b\right)a}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(\sqrt{ax}-\pi\sqrt{\left(n+b\right)/x}\right)^{2}}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}}
 $$ $$\overset{w=\frac{n+b}{x}}{=}\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n\geq0}r_{2}\left(n\right)\frac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\left(n+b\right)a}}}{\sqrt{n+b}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(\sqrt{a\left(n+b\right)/w}-\pi\sqrt{w}\right)^{2}}\frac{dw}{\sqrt{w}}$$ $$=\sum_{n\geq0}r_{2}\left(n\right)\frac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt{\left(n+b\right)a}}}{\sqrt{n+b}}.
 $$

Comment: So nice an answer. +1 won't do it justice so I will start a bounty.

Comment: An amazing piece of work!  I can never understand how people do such things!  +1 for divine guidance, just like Ramanujan claimed!

Comment: well done marco (+1)

Comment: Impressive and elegant! +1

Comment: (+1) I was ready to write "it looks like a consequence of the Poisson summation formula" when I noticed your answer. Well done.

Comment: By chance I happened to find a proof of this formula (not as detailed as your answer) but more as a hint in Hardy's book *"Ramanujan: Twelve Lectures on Subjects Suggested by His Life and Work"* on page 81. He gives some further applications of this formula for estimating the sum $\sum_{n \leq x}r_{2}(n)$.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely coming from p. 81-82 of Hardy's Ramanujan: Twelve Lectures on Subjects Suggested by his Life and Work, including the exact same typo in the expansion of the Jacobi $\theta_3$ function.  Would've been nice if Marco cited his source