# Simplifying integral:$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\exp\left(-\left(u^2+{ {\alpha^2}\over {16u^2t}}\right)\right)}~\mathrm{d}u$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, gaussian-integral

$$I(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\exp\left(-\left(u^2+{ {\alpha^2}\over {16u^2t}}\right)\right)}~\mathrm{d}u $$

where $\alpha$ and $t$ are positive constant.

P.S.I would like to edit this problem, because I found my mistake about inner sign.

Thanks!

Comment: what do we know about $$\alpha,t$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner $\alpha$ and $t$ are constant.

Comment: Is t < 0? (if not, I believe this diverges)

Comment: @jschnei: t>0 .

Comment: Is the inner minus sign supposed to be a +? Right now, if $t > 0$ then note that (for $u$ sufficiently close to $0$) $\exp(C/u^2 - u^2) > 1/u$ and therefore this integral diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** 
For any $f$ such that $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u)\: \mathrm{d}x<\infty$, we have (see a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left/963490#963490))

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(u-\frac{s}{u}\right)\mathrm{d}u=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u)\: \mathrm{d}u, \quad s>0. \tag1
> $$

Apply it to $f(u)=e^{-u^2}$, you get

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(u-s/u)^2}\mathrm{d}u=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-u^2} \mathrm{d}u=\sqrt{\pi}, \quad s>0. \tag2
$$

or

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2-s^2/u^{2}}\mathrm{d}u=\sqrt{\pi}\:e^{-2s}\tag3
$$ then put $s=\dfrac{\alpha}{4\sqrt{t}}$ to obtain the value of your integral, noticing that $f$ is **even** here.

Comment: Well, this is a nice development, but unfortunately does not evaluate the integral of interest.

Comment: @Dr.MV I think there is typo in the OP integral, and what was meant was what I solved. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, otherwise the integral doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the integral of interest $I$ is

$$I=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\left(u^2+\frac{\alpha^2}{16tu^2}\right)}du$$

First, we let $a^2=\frac{\alpha^2}{16t}$ and write

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-a\left(\frac{u^2}{a}+\frac{a}{u^2}\right)}du\\\\
&=e^{-2a}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-a\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{a}}-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{u}\right)^2}du\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, enforcing the substitution $u/\sqrt{a}\to -\sqrt{a}/u$, we find

$$I=e^{-2a}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-a\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{a}}-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{u}\right)^2} \frac{a}{u^2}\,du \tag 2$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ and dividing by $2$  yields

$$I=e^{-2a}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-a\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{a}}-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{u}\right)^2} \left(1+\frac{a}{u^2}\right)\,du $$

Making one final substitution $\frac{u}{\sqrt{a}}-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{u}\,\to\,u$ and we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I=e^{2a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-au^2}\sqrt{a}du=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-2a}=\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\alpha/2\sqrt{t}}}$$

Comment: ${u}^{2} - \frac{\alpha^2}{16tu^2}$ there should be a $-$ not $+$

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Check the original integral.  It does not converge.  Now check all the other answers and see what we are assuming.

Comment: Ah okay, because I didn't notice the convergence of the integral I was just comparing to the original question

Comment: @OussamaBoussif But why did you single me out when others assumed the same?

Comment: Because I just went through them quickly if you see closely you'll find that they did the same as you at the end and I didn't see that

Answer (score 2):

Using 
$$x^{2} - \frac{a^{2}}{x^{2}} = \left(x - \frac{i a}{x} \right)^{2} + 2 i a $$
then
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \left(u^{2} - \frac{\alpha^{2}}{16 \, t \, u^{2}}\right)} \, du 
= e^{-2 i a} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \left(u - \frac{i a}{u}\right)^{2}} \, du
\end{align}
where $4 \sqrt{t} \, a = \alpha$. Let $u = \sqrt{i a} x$ to obtain
\begin{align} \tag{1}
e^{2 i a} \, I = \sqrt{i a} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- i a \, \left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}} \, dx.
\end{align}
Now let $x \to \frac{1}{x}$ to obtain
\begin{align}\tag{2}
e^{2 i a} \, I &= \sqrt{i a} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-i a \, \left( x - \frac{1}{x} \right)^{2}} \, \frac{dx}{x^{2}}. 
\end{align}
Adding equations (1) and (2) lead to
\begin{align}
\frac{2 \, e^{2 i a}}{\sqrt{i a}} \, I = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-i a \, \left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}} \, \left(1 + \frac{1}{x^{2}}\right) \, dx. 
\end{align}
Let $y = x + \frac{1}{x}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{2 \, e^{2 i a}}{\sqrt{i a}} \, I = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-i a \, y^{2}} \, dy 
\end{align}
Set $y = \sqrt{\frac{x}{i a}}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{2 \, e^{2 i a}}{\sqrt{i a}} \, I = \frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{i a}}
\end{align}
From this the integral is given by
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \left(u^{2} - \frac{a^{2}}{u^{2}}\right)} \, du = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \, e^{-2 i a}.
\end{align}
When $4 \sqrt{t} a = \alpha$ then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \left(u^{2} - \frac{\alpha^{2}}{16 \, t \, u^{2}}\right)} \, du = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \, e^{- \frac{i \, \alpha}{2 \sqrt{t}}}.
\end{align}

Comment: .... But, this integral diverges at $0$ ....

Comment: @Dr.MV As the lower limit goes to zero the integral does diverge. It would have been less troublesome had $u^{2} + \frac{a^{2}}{u^{2}}$ been in the integrand.

Comment: Yes, that is why I succumbed and just assumed the plus sign.

Comment: @Dr.MV After posting the last comment I saw your solution. The questioner and general viewers have some integral evaluations to learn from. As always great solution.

Comment: I have to give you credit for this one.  I recall a similar question for which you gave a similar answer.  So, thank you for the lesson .. +1 here.  Check out OlivierOloa's answer.  It relied on a more general result that we might be able to use down the line.