# $\int_{0}^{\infty} \text{e}^{c z x} \frac{y}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \text{e}^{- \frac{y^2}{2x} } x^{- \frac{3}{2}} \, \text{d}x = \text{e}^{y\sqrt{2cz}} $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $\nu<0$ and $\xi,c >0$. I want to show the identity
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \text{e}^{c \nu \eta}  \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \text{e}^{- \frac{\xi^2}{2 \eta} } \eta^{- \frac{3}{2}}    \, \text{d}\eta=\text{e}^{-\xi\sqrt{2c|\nu|}}.
$$
My attempt: To evaluate the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \text{e}^{c \nu \eta}  \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \text{e}^{- \frac{\xi^2}{2 \eta} } \eta^{- \frac{3}{2}}    \, \text{d}\eta = \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{e}^{\frac{2c\nu \eta^2-\xi^2}{2 \eta}}  \eta^{- \frac{3}{2}}    \, \text{d}\eta=\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \text{e}^{\frac{-2c|\nu| \eta^2-\xi^2}{2 \eta}}  \eta^{- \frac{3}{2}}    \, \text{d}\eta.
$$
we make the substitution
$$
u= \frac{\xi-\sqrt{2c|\nu|}\eta}{\sqrt{2\eta}}
$$
or equivalently
$$
\eta = \frac{u^2+ \xi \sqrt{2 c |\nu|}-\sqrt{2\xi u^2  \sqrt{2c |\nu| }  +u^4}}{2c|\nu|}.
$$
Because of
$$
\text{e}^{-u^2} = \text{e}^{\frac{-\xi^2+2\xi\eta\sqrt{2c|\nu|} -2c|\nu|\eta^2  }{2\eta}}, \qquad \text{e}^{\frac{-2c|\nu|\eta^2-\xi^2}{2\eta}} = \text{e}^{-u^2-\xi\sqrt{2c|\nu|}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}\eta}= \frac{- \sqrt{2} \xi  -  \sqrt{2}\eta \sqrt{2c|\nu|}  }{4\eta^{\frac{3}{2}}}, \qquad \eta^{-\frac{3}{2}} \,  \text{d}\eta   = -  \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}\xi  + \sqrt{2} \left(\frac{u^2+ \xi \sqrt{2 c |\nu|}-\sqrt{2\xi u^2  \sqrt{2c |\nu| }  +u^4}}{2c|\nu|}\right) \sqrt{2c|\nu|}}  \, \text{d}u
$$
we get
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \text{e}^{c \nu \eta} \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \text{e}^{- \frac{\xi^2}{2 \eta} } \eta^{- \frac{3}{2}}    \, \text{d}\eta = \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{e}^{-u^2-\xi\sqrt{2c|\nu|}}    \frac{2 \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2c|\nu|}}{u^2+ 2 \xi \sqrt{2 c |\nu|}-\sqrt{2\xi u^2  \sqrt{2c |\nu| }  +u^4}}  \, \text{d}u.
$$
Now we write
$$
 \frac{2 \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2c|\nu|}}{u^2+ 2 \xi \sqrt{2 c |\nu|}-\sqrt{2\xi u^2  \sqrt{2c |\nu| }  +u^4}} =\frac{1}{\xi} + \frac{2 \sqrt{2} \xi \zeta - u^2- 2 \xi \zeta+\sqrt{2\xi u^2  \zeta  +u^4} }{u^2 \xi+ 2 \xi^2 \zeta- \xi \sqrt{2\xi u^2  \zeta  +u^4}}.
$$
To get 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \text{e}^{c \nu \eta}  \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \text{e}^{- \frac{\xi^2}{2 \eta} } \eta^{- \frac{3}{2}}    \, \text{d}\eta =
\text{e}^{-\xi\sqrt{2c|\nu|}} 
$$
I need that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{e}^{-u^2} \frac{2 \sqrt{2} \xi \zeta - u^2- 2 \xi \zeta+\sqrt{2\xi u^2  \zeta  +u^4} }{u^2 \xi+ 2 \xi^2 \zeta- \xi \sqrt{2\xi u^2  \zeta  +u^4}} \, \text{d}u=0.
$$
How can I show this?

Comment: On this site, questions that merely state an isolated problem are often put on hold. You can improve the question by including motivation and context. Where did you encounter the problem? Why is it of interest? What have you tried already? Where did you get stuck? You can edit the question to include that information.

Comment: @CarlMummert Have you seen the first version of this question? The OP has really worked hard on it. But he just changed the question at the end. I invite the downvoter to re-consider his/her vote.

Comment: @user_24938: we *want* you to indicate what yo have tried on the question - please don't remove it all! We also look for motivation. Why is this particular integral of interest? There are unlimited numbers of integrals that could be studied, so they can't all be interesting - what were you looking at when you encountered this integral? That sort of information helps improve the post, it helps others find questions of interest, and it helps others write answers that are more focused on your particular situation.

Comment: `deleted 2374 characters in body` Why?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Sorry to ask, but why do you see fit to produce near-duplicate answers of already posted answers? (Additionally, note that more gifted searchers than I am, would probably find on the spot several exact duplicates of this question.)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** If you make the change of variable $t=x^{-1/2}$, $dt=-\dfrac12 x^{-3/2}dx$,  in the following equivalent integral you obtain
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{\large -(b^2x+\frac{a^2}x)}x^{-3/2} dx=2\int_0^{\infty}e^{ -a^2t^2-b^2/t^2}dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ -a^2t^2-b^2/t^2}dt
$$
One may then recall that, for any integrable function $f$, we have

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(t-\frac{s}{t}\right)\mathrm{d}t=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)\: \mathrm{d}t, \quad s>0. \tag1
> $$

Applying it to $f(t)=e^{-a^2t^2}$, $a>0$, $b>0$, $s=b/a$, you get

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\large -a^2(t-\frac{b}{a t})^2}\mathrm{d}t=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-a^2t^2} \mathrm{d}t=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}a, \quad s>0. \tag2
$$

Thus

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-a^2t^2-b^2/t^{2}}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}a\:e^{-2ab}.\tag3
$$ This is a path to obtain your initial integral.

Comment: @user_249438 Here are many proofs of $(1)$ : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left/963490#963490   Thanks.