# Integrals using substitution $x\mapsto x+\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: integration, reference-request

Do you have some links to questions with integrals that require the substitution $x\mapsto x+\frac{1}{x}$ (as a trick)?

I know this trick, but I can't seem to find any integrals to practice it..

Comment: How about $\int \cos (x + \frac{1}{x}) (1-\frac{1}{x^2}) \, dx$? :)

Comment: @MathMajor Haha well I mean integrals which require this substitution as a 'trick'.. :)

Comment: I suppose you want exercises that involve _multiple_ substitutions, among which $x \mapsto x + 1/x$? Otherwise, knowing that you need the very substitution you asked for would render them trivial, right?

Comment: Worth mentioning: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left/963490