# How to show $e^{-\sqrt{2\lambda }x}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda u} (2\pi u^3)^{-1/2} x \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2u}) du$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, closed-form

I want to show the following integral:

$$e^{-\sqrt{2\lambda }x}=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda u} (2\pi u^3)^{-1/2} x \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2u}) du$$

Could anyone give me some hints on evaluating the right hand side?

Answer (score 1):

By the change of variable $v=\dfrac{ x}{\sqrt{2}\cdot u^{1/2}}$ we obtain $dv=-\dfrac{x}{2\sqrt{2}}\cdot (u^{3})^{-1/2}du$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}\! e^{-\lambda u} (2\pi u^3)^{-1/2} x \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2u}) du&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\!\!\int_0^{\infty}e^{ -v^2-\lambda x^2/(2v^2)}dv
\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\!\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ -v^2-\lambda x^2/(2v^2)}dv \tag1
\end{align}
$$
one may then recall that, for any integrable function $f$, we have (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left/963490#963490))

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(v-\frac{a}{v}\right)\mathrm{d}v=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(v)\: \mathrm{d}v, \quad a>0. \tag2
> $$

Applying it to $f(v)=e^{-v^2}$, gives

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(v-a/v)^2}\mathrm{d}v=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-v^2} \mathrm{d}v=\sqrt{\pi}, \quad a>0. \tag3
$$

Thus from $(3)$, expanding the square, we get

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-v^2-a^2/v^{2}}\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\pi}\:e^{-2a}\tag4
$$ then, using $(1)$, we deduce the announced result.

Comment: +1. To compensate any down-vote. I guess 'some' people down-vote when they don't understand the answer. The 'right way' must be to ask for a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets $\ds{\quad u \equiv A\expo{2\theta}\,,\quad A > 0.\quad}$ The $\ds{A}$-constant will be chosen in a 'convenient way' as shown below.

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\lambda u}\pars{2\pi u^{3}}^{-1/2}\,x\,
\exp\pars{-\,{\phantom{^{2}}x^{2} \over 2u}}\,\dd u}
\\[5mm] = &\
{x \over \root{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}A^{-3/2}\expo{-3\theta}
\exp\pars{-\lambda A\expo{2\theta} -\,{\phantom{^{2}}x^{2} \over 2}\,A^{-1}
\expo{-2\theta}}\,\pars{2A\expo{2\theta}}\,\dd\theta\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
We'll choose $\ds{A > 0}$ to satisfies
$\ds{\lambda A = x^{2}A^{-1}/2 \implies A = \verts{x}/\root{2\lambda}}$. \eqref{1} is reduced to:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\lambda u}\pars{2\pi u^{3}}^{-1/2}\,x\,
\exp\pars{-\,{\phantom{^{2}}x^{2} \over 2u}}\,\dd u}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2x \over \root{2\pi}}\pars{\verts{x} \over \root{2\lambda}}^{-1/2}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\lambda\,{\verts{x} \over \root{2\lambda}}\,\bracks{2\cosh\pars{2\theta}}}\expo{-\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
2^{3/4}{\lambda^{1/4} \over \root{\pi}}{x \over \verts{x}^{1/2}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-\root{2\lambda}\verts{x}\bracks{2\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1}}
\bracks{\cosh\pars{\theta} - \sinh\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{\quad\cosh\pars{2\theta} = 2\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta} + 1\quad}$ and
>   $\ds{\quad\expo{-\theta} = \cosh\pars{\theta} - \sinh\pars{\theta}}$.

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\lambda u}\pars{2\pi u^{3}}^{-1/2}\,x\,
\exp\pars{-\,{\phantom{^{2}}x^{2} \over 2u}}\,\dd u}
\\[5mm] = &\
2^{3/4}{\lambda^{1/4} \over \root{\pi}}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{x}\verts{x}^{1/2}
\exp\pars{-\root{2\lambda}\verts{x}}\times
\\[3mm] &\
\bracks{2\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-2\root{2\lambda}\verts{x}\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta}}\cosh\pars{\theta}
\,\dd\theta}
\\[1cm] \stackrel{t\ =\ \sinh\pars{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,&\
 2^{7/4}{\lambda^{1/4} \over \root{\pi}}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{x}\verts{x}^{1/2}
\exp\pars{-\root{2\lambda}\verts{x}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-2\root{2\lambda}\verts{x}t^{2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
2^{7/4}{\lambda^{1/4} \over \root{\pi}}\,\mrm{sgn}\pars{x}\verts{x}^{1/2}
\exp\pars{-\root{2\lambda}\verts{x}}
\bracks{\root{\pi} \over 2^{7/4}\lambda^{1/4}\verts{x}^{1/2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{\mrm{sgn}\pars{x}\exp\pars{-\root{2\lambda}\verts{x}}}
\end{align}