# Hints on integrating (rather complicated) exponential function

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I am interested in computing the following integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-t)^2}{t} - t\right)\, dt. $$
A hint is good enough for me!

Comment: Possibly useful: $\frac{(x-t)^2+t^2}{t}=\frac{2t^2-2tx+x^2}{t}=\frac{2(t-\frac{1}{2}x)^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2}{t}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. Make the change of variable
$$
u=\sqrt{t}, \quad du=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t}},
$$ giving
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-t)^2}{t} - t\right)\, dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-2u^2-\frac{x^2}{u^2}-2 x\right)\, du
$$ then use [G. Boole's result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left/963490#963490):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(u-\frac{a}{u}\right)\mathrm{d}u=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u)\: \mathrm{d}u,\quad a>0.
$$

Comment: What are you proposing for $f$? I tried $f(x)=-x^2$ but I still have an extra $-u^2$ term.

Comment: One may observe that the argument of $\exp\left(-2u^2-\frac{x^2}{u^2}-2 x\right) $ rewrites $-2\left(u-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}u}\right)^2-2\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)x$. The term $-2\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)x$ is a constant going 'outside' the integral. Thus $f(u)=\exp (-2u^2)$ is fine and easy to integrate over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Just did the calculation and it coincides with the given solution. Many thanks (:

Comment: @Chee Han You are very welcome.

Comment: (Boole-)Glasser saves the day (again)...$(+1)$