# Showing $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left({-a x^2 -\frac{b}{x^2}}\right) \,dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab} }$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

How to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp{\left({-a x^2 -\frac{b}{x^2}}\right)} \,dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}.$$

Comment: You can complete in the square.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\frac{a}x\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\: \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: @user1952009, see my answer.

Comment: If $a<0$, the integral diverges anyway.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Greatly thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left({-a x^2 -\frac{b}{x^2}}\right) = -\left({a x^2 -2\sqrt{ab}+\frac{b}{x^2}}\right)-2\sqrt{ab} =-a\left({x -\frac{\sqrt{b/a}}{x}}\right)^2-2\sqrt{ab}  $$

Then using that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(x-\frac{c}x\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\: \mathrm{d}x$$

With $f(x) = e^{-ax^2}$ and $c=\sqrt{b/a}$

$$I =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp{\left({-a x^2 -\frac{b}{x^2}}\right)} \,dx =e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}$$

---

**Reference**

[How to prove $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)dx?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left?rq=1)

Comment: Indeed, you can make $x-1/x$ appear directly

Comment: Still, can you prove that critical identity?

Comment: @HocNgo, not that difficult. see the reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That identity is quite useful!