# Integration of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{x^2 }{x^4 + a^4}\,dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_\infty^\infty \dfrac{x^2 }{x^4 + a^4}\,dx$$

The following question was given with the limits $\infty$ to $\infty$ but I believe that it was a typo and the lower limit would be $- \infty $ but with that, the question would become

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{x^2 }{x^4 + a^4}\,dx$$

And I was perplexed how to solve that. If I take $x^3=t$ then the numerator would become $dt$ but in the denominator I have $x^4$ and I couldn't convert it to $x^3$. So I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Try the substitution $x=1/t $.

Comment: You can use that 

\begin{eqnarray}
   \int \frac{2u^2}{1+u^4} \mathrm{d} u &=& \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \log \left(\frac{u^2-\sqrt{2} u+1}{u^2+\sqrt{2} u+1}\right) + \\ 
    &\phantom{=}& \frac{\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} u+1\right) -\tan ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt{2} u\right) }{\sqrt{2}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai You forgot the $+C$.

Comment: @projectilemotion Too late to edit :)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**. Assume $a \ne0$. One may write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{x^2 }{x^4 + a^4}\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1 }{x^2 + \frac{a^4}{x^2}}\,dx
\\\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1 }{\left(x -\frac{a^2}{x}\right)^2+2a^2}\,dx
\\\\&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{1 }{x^2+2a^2}\,dx
\\\\&=\frac{\pi\:\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{|a|}
\end{align}
$$ where we have used
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x -\frac{a^2}{x}\right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\:dx
$$ proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left/963490#963490).

Comment: It should be $|a|$ I guess.

Comment: @Zaid Alyafeai Sure, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Consider the standard semi circle contour in the upper half of the complex plane, with $\gamma_r=\{re^{ix},x\in(0,\pi)\}$ and $\delta_r=[-r,r]$.  It thus follows swiftly that, assuming $a>0$:

$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{z^2}{z^4+a^4}\ dz=0$$

$$\begin{align}\lim_{r\to\infty}\oint\frac{z^2}{z^4+a^4}\ dz&=\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_{\delta_r}\frac{z^2}{z^4+a^4}\ dz\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^4+a^4}\ dx\\& =2\pi i\left(\frac1{4ae^{\pi i/4}}+\frac1{4ae^{3\pi i/4}}\right)\\&=\frac\pi{a\sqrt2}\end{align}$$