# How to prove $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x-1/x}}{x \sqrt{x}} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{e^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I went into this integration, 
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x-1/x}}{x \sqrt{x}} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{e^2}$$
[Wolfram Online Integral Calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp(-x-1%2Fx)%2Fx%5E(3%2F2)+dx+from+x%3D0+to+%2Binfinity) gives the result above without process. May I know how to derive the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After letting $x=1/s^2$ we get
$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x-1/x}}{x \sqrt{x}} dx&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-s^2-1/s^2} ds=\frac{2}{e^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-(s-1/s)^2} ds\\
&=\frac{1}{e^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(s-1/s)^2} ds=\frac{1}{e^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s^2} ds=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{e^2}\end{align}$$
where at the last two steps we used [How to prove $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left(x - \frac{1}{x}\right)dx?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left/963490) and then the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: @athos Thanks for the edit!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x-\frac1x$. Then $\mathrm{d}u=\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x-1/x}}{x\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2-1/x^2}}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2-1/x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2-2}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag3\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{e^2}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto x^2$
$(2)$: substitute $x\mapsto 1/x$
$(3)$: average $(1)$ and $(2)$ and substitute $u=x-1/x$
$(4)$: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u=\sqrt\pi$