# Finding the value of integral.

Tags: definite-integrals

If $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx= 1,$
Find value of $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-\frac{1}{x}) dx$.

I tried substituting $x$ as $\frac{1}{t}$, but nothing is happening.
In the denominator, $1+x^2$ is left.

Comment: Hint: Try substituting $x=e^u$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Your substitution only works for $x\in(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @matematicoschibchas hmm, you're right. You can split it the integral range into positive and negative $x$, then use $x=-e^{-u}$ for the negative part.

Answer (score 3):

One may recall the following [property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html)
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\left( x - \frac{1}{x} \right) \, dx
$$ proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left?rq=1).