# Prove the following and use it to evaluate the integral:

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

I want to prove that:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac1x\right)dx$$
And use the result of this proof to evaluate:$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}dx$$

Comment: Review [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457231/how-to-prove-int-infty-infty-fxdx-int-infty-infty-f-left/1461393#1461393).

Comment: Thank you both so much! That really helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to apply it to
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}dx
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{(x-\frac1x)^2+2}dx
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+2}dx=\frac\pi{\sqrt2}
$$

Comment: Amazing. World's largest thank you!